# PowerBI how to combine values from 2 tables into a URL dynamically?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Using some sample data, I have table1 with the following values:

| Name |
| --- |
| Bob |
| John |
| Mary |

and table 2 with the following values:

| folder |
| --- |
| documents |
| pictures |
| videos |

I need to select one value from each table to build a URL. the final URL would be something like:
"https://example.com/Bob/Documents"
"http://example.com/Mary/Pictures"

The person viewing the report needs to choose a name and a folder, then click on a button to load the url.

I haven't been able to do this yet. I can do a dynamic column and get the name, but can't make it get the folder.

Folder table can be rebuild in another way if it solves the problem. Name table comes from Sharepoint and can't be altered.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a measure using the below DAX, and if it helps then please consider Accept it as the solution.

```
Measure 5 = 
VAR X = SELECTEDVALUE(Tabl11[Name])
VAR Y = SELECTEDVALUE(Table2[Folder])

RETURN "https://example.com/" & X & "/" & Y
```

[image: Output1]

[image: Output2]

Comment: I had used measures before but it was not working, I thought that for some reason measures wouldn't work as links.... Turns out the button was somehow bugged. I deleted the button, made a new one and put the measure back, it worked. go figure. Thank you

Comment: Yeah sometimes Power BI can be buggy,  it's better to restart once. I faced some filter issue yesterday, luckily I closed and restarted my whole system after wasting 6 hours on something which should have been there in the first place.